# Properties.Settings.Default loads previous project value

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, app-config, configuration-files

I copied a version 4.1 project (VS2008) to a version 5.0 project (VS2013) and renamed all text values from 4.1 to 5.0.
In the settings designer (Project -> 'ProjectName' properties) there is a setting named ProjectName. This was changed to 'AppName_5.0'.

In our 'About' screen, this setting is loaded and displayed on a label.
However, in debug mode, the about screen keeps displaying 'AppName_4.1'??

```
label1.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.ProjectName; //Displays 4.1?
```

I don't understand where this value keeps coming from? In the AppName_5.0.exe.config file, the value is AppName_5.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently we're using a CustomSettingsProvider, which stores the settings files in another location ... :-/

Answer (score 1):

.config also stored in %localappdata%\yourApp

found [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/80b28443-c5a9-45ad-b7c9-d046a389f30c/old-value-from-propertiessettingsdefault-still-appears-at-runtime?forum=csharpide)

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed this happening on some projects when the .config file and the project settings are out of sync - try going to the project's properties, under the Settings tab.
This should prompt you to load the values from the .config file.

Comment: Under Project -> Properties -> Settings, the correct value is displayed. In bin\Debug\AppName_5.0.exe.config, also the correct value is present. Changes to forms etc. are also correctly displayed, only the settings keep loading old values ...